# Server-side render data when using Apollo Client with NextJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, next.js, apollo-client

My component currently hydrates on the browser, something I'd love to avoid. When you visit the link, I want it to come pre-hydrated with all the data it needs to display, i.e. rendered on the server. Currently, the component looks like this:

```
import { graphql } from "react-apollo";
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import withData from "../../apollo/with-data";
import getPostsQuery from '../../apollo/schemas/getPostsQuery.graphql';


const renderers = {
  paragraph: (props) => <Typography variant="body2" gutterBottom {...props} />,
};

const GET_POSTS = gql`${getPostsQuery}`;

const PostList = ({data: {error, loading, posts}}) => {
  let payload;
  if(error) {
    payload = (<div>There was an error!</div>);
  } else if(loading) {
    payload = (<div>Loading...</div>);
  } else {
    payload = (
      <>
        {posts.map((post) => (
          <div>
            <div>{post.title}</div>
            <div>{post.body}</div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </>
    );
  }
    return payload;
};

export default withData(graphql(GET_POSTS)(PostList));
```

As you can see, it displays the text `Loading...` at first as it fetches the posts in the background. I don't want that. I want it to already come **pre-hydrated** with the fetched data.

For reference, my Apollo initializations look like this:

```
// apollo/with-data.js

import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { ApolloProvider, getDataFromTree } from "react-apollo";
import initApollo from "./init-apollo";

export default ComposedComponent => {
  return class WithData extends React.Component {
    static displayName = `WithData(${ComposedComponent.displayName})`;
    static propTypes = {
      serverState: PropTypes.object.isRequired
    };

    static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
      const headers = ctx.req ? ctx.req.headers : {};
      let serverState = {};

      // Evaluate the composed component's getInitialProps()
      let composedInitialProps = {};
      if (ComposedComponent.getInitialProps) {
        composedInitialProps = await ComposedComponent.getInitialProps(ctx);
      }

      // Run all graphql queries in the component tree
      // and extract the resulting data
      if (!process.browser) {
        const apollo = initApollo(headers);
        // Provide the `url` prop data in case a graphql query uses it
        const url = { query: ctx.query, pathname: ctx.pathname };

        // Run all graphql queries
        const app = (
          <ApolloProvider client={apollo}>
            <ComposedComponent url={url} {...composedInitialProps} />
          </ApolloProvider>
        );
        await getDataFromTree(app);

        // Extract query data from the Apollo's store
        const state = apollo.getInitialState();

        serverState = {
          apollo: {
            // Make sure to only include Apollo's data state
            data: state.data
          }
        };
      }

      return {
        serverState,
        headers,
        ...composedInitialProps
      };
    }

    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.apollo = initApollo(this.props.headers, this.props.serverState);
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <ApolloProvider client={this.apollo}>
          <ComposedComponent {...this.props} />
        </ApolloProvider>
      );
    }
  };
};
```

```
// apollo/init-apollo.js

import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';
import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client';
import { ApolloLink } from 'apollo-link';
import { onError } from 'apollo-link-error';
import { HttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http';
import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch';

let apolloClient = null;

// Polyfill fetch() on the server (used by apollo-client)
if (!process.browser) {
  global.fetch = fetch;
}

const create = (headers, initialState) => new ApolloClient({
  initialState,
  link: ApolloLink.from([
    onError(({ graphQLErrors, networkError }) => {
      if (graphQLErrors) {
        graphQLErrors.forEach(({ message, locations, path }) => console.log(
          `[GraphQL error]: Message: ${message}, Location: ${locations}, Path: ${path}`,
        ));
      }
      if (networkError) console.log(`[Network error]: ${networkError}`);
    }),
    new HttpLink({
      // uri: 'https://dev.schandillia.com/graphql',
      uri: process.env.CMS,
      credentials: 'same-origin',
    }),
  ]),
  ssrMode: !process.browser, // Disables forceFetch on the server (so queries are only run once)
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});

export default function initApollo(headers, initialState = {}) {
  // Make sure to create a new client for every server-side request so that data
  // isn't shared between connections (which would be bad)
  if (!process.browser) {
    return create(headers, initialState);
  }

  // Reuse client on the client-side
  if (!apolloClient) {
    apolloClient = create(headers, initialState);
  }

  return apolloClient;
}
```

**UPDATE**: I tried incorporating the official withApollo example at https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-apollo into my project but it throws an invariant error on `getDataFromTree()`:

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.

I used the exact same code as in the example repo, for the `/init/apollo.js`, `/components/blog/PostList.jsx`, and `/pages/Blog/jsx` files. The only difference in my specific case is that I have an explicit `_app.jsx` that reads as follows:

```
/* eslint-disable max-len */

import '../static/styles/fonts.scss';
import '../static/styles/style.scss';
import '../static/styles/some.css';

import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import { ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/styles';
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import withRedux from 'next-redux-wrapper';
import App, {
  Container,
} from 'next/app';
import Head from 'next/head';
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

import makeStore from '../reducers';
import mainTheme from '../themes/main-theme';
import getSessIDFromCookies from '../utils/get-sessid-from-cookies';
import getLanguageFromCookies from '../utils/get-language-from-cookies';
import getUserTokenFromCookies from '../utils/get-user-token-from-cookies';
import removeFbHash from '../utils/remove-fb-hash';

class MyApp extends App {
  static async getInitialProps({ Component, ctx }) {
    let userToken;
    let sessID;
    let language;

    if (ctx.isServer) {
      ctx.store.dispatch({ type: 'UPDATEIP', payload: ctx.req.headers['x-real-ip'] });

      userToken = getUserTokenFromCookies(ctx.req);
      sessID = getSessIDFromCookies(ctx.req);
      language = getLanguageFromCookies(ctx.req);
      const dictionary = require(`../dictionaries/${language}`);
      ctx.store.dispatch({ type: 'SETLANGUAGE', payload: dictionary });
      if(ctx.res) {
        if(ctx.res.locals) {
          if(!ctx.res.locals.authenticated) {
            userToken = null;
            sessID = null;
          }
        }
      }
      if (userToken && sessID) { // TBD: validate integrity of sessID
        const userInfo = jwt.verify(userToken, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
        ctx.store.dispatch({ type: 'ADDUSERINFO', payload: userInfo });
      }
      ctx.store.dispatch({ type: 'ADDSESSION', payload: sessID }); // component will be able to read from store's state when rendered
    }
    const pageProps = Component.getInitialProps ? await Component.getInitialProps(ctx) : {};
    return { pageProps };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // Remove the server-side injected CSS.
    const jssStyles = document.querySelector('#jss-server-side');
    if (jssStyles) {
      jssStyles.parentNode.removeChild(jssStyles);
    }
    // Register serviceWorker
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) { navigator.serviceWorker.register('/serviceWorker.js'); }

    // Handle FB's ugly redirect URL hash
    removeFbHash(window, document);
  }

  render() {
    const { Component, pageProps, store } = this.props;

    return (
      <Container>
        <Head>
          <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=0, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, shrink-to-fit=no" />
          <meta httpEquiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
          <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-touch-icon.png" />
          <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon-32x32.png" />
          <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="194x194" href="/favicon-194x194.png" />
          <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="192x192" href="/android-chrome-192x192.png" />
          <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon-16x16.png" />
          <link rel="manifest" href="/site.webmanifest" />
          <link rel="mask-icon" href="/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#663300" />
          <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c" />
          <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="/mstile-144x144.png" />
        </Head>
        <ThemeProvider theme={mainTheme}>
          {/* CssBaseline kickstart an elegant, consistent, and simple baseline to build upon. */}
          <CssBaseline />
            <Provider store={store}>
              <Component {...pageProps} />
            </Provider>
        </ThemeProvider>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

export default withRedux(makeStore)(MyApp);
```

Getting rid of this file is not an option as this is where I'm handling some pre-load cookie logic.

The repo, for reference, is up at https://github.com/amitschandillia/proost/tree/master/web

Comment: Have you checked out the SSR docs? The in-memory cache can be restored with data from the server: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/features/server-side-rendering/. Not sure how that looks when working with next.js.

Comment: Exactly. I did go through their docs here: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/features/server-side-rendering/. But didn't find anything pertaining to isomorphic setups like Next.

Comment: Just wanted to say I recently (Feb 28, 2020) used the https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-apollo reference implementation with success. My versions: apollo-client@2.6.8, @apollo/react-ssr@3.1.3, next@9.2.2. The github issues suggesting using getMarkupFromTree were a waste of time for me.

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 key things you want to achieve when using Next.js and Apollo: SSR and Cached network data.
It is a difficult balance to achieve both. But it is possible.

The way to do it is:

1. In your getInitialProps function, use the apolloclient to get your data which should be visible on page load. If done correctly, data is retrieved along side with HTML ie (SSR) and there is no annoying loaders showing on your initial page load.

Now if you have some page data that you need to edit, add or delete and you want the page to update after your changes without refreshing the page, above is not enough.
Because if for instance, you edit data, the typical/recommended Apollo approach is not to do anything. Apollo handles it all magically for you. Except the initial data must have come from the apollo cache and it must have an Id field.
Now as you have loaded the initial data directly from the server, it is most likely, you did not read the data from a previously cached data.

So Step 2 below is then required to enable the auto-refresh of data on data changes.

2. Any data you know you are going to edit must come from the cache. So don't be tempted to use data from getInitialProps to populate such data. Rather you may use useQuery or its equivalents to query the same data using the same Graphql query you used for the getInitialProps query. Now what happens is that apollo does not take the data from the network this time but from the previous query from the server. And then all of a sudden, instead of seeing loading... everywhere, you see data being loaded instantly. And then at the same time when you edit the data it is also updated immediately because the data was populated from the cache in the first place and now updates changes the cached data and refreshes your page automatically.

This way, you continue to use all your favourite and the latest tools such as useQuery and getDataFromTree without much ado.

Answer (score 0):

Some Research to Help:

I believe you're supposed to use `getMarkupFromTree` as seen suggested in this issue https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo/issues/3251 and how to implement https://github.com/trojanowski/react-apollo-hooks/issues/52 .

It appears that if you want to use hooks you need @trojanowski 's `react-apollo-hooks` package.

Some have said this solution doesn't work though. Some suggest that it has some ineficiencies, for example, it renders the entire mark up twice, once by next and once to get apollo queries. In response, they suggest doing something like calling the query directly in get initial props, it's just more work than should be done, since the ssr features should be ready-to-go out-of-the-box.